# F# and type providers under linux OS

Tags: linux, f#

I have a problem with type providers. I have simple provider that is reading configuration file that is located in same directory as app:

```
type Communication = XmlProvider<"communication.config">

let GetConnectionConfiguration : Option<IPAddress> * int = 
  let root = Communication.GetSample()
```

Now config file is rather simple one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
    <Server Ip="127.0.0.1" Port="50000" />
 </configuration>
```

When i run this code in windows all is OK and works perfectly, but when I run this under ubuntu I am getting

> Could not find a part of the path '/mnt/c/Workspace/Playground/LiveServer/Hub/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/publish/C:\Workspace\Playground\LiveServer\Hub/communication.config'.Blockquote

What could be the source root of this problem?

Comment: Looks like the type provider remembers the absolute path to the config file at compile time, and loads that on `GetSample()`. You're not supposed to use `GetSample()` in production, it's just for debugging. Use `.Load()` or `.Parse()` instead.